# static class and multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a static helper class that I'm using a lot in a web app. Suppose that the app receives about 20 requests per second for a sustained period of time and that, by magic, two requests ask the static class to do some work at the exact same nanosecond.

What happens when this happens?

To provide some context, the class is a used to perform a linq-to-sql query: it receives a few parameters, including the UserID, and returns a list of custom objects.

thanks.

Comment: the unstoppable force stops and the immovable object moves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when this happens?

If your methods are [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) then they are thread safe and what will happen is that chances are they will work. If those static methods rely on some shared state and you haven't synchronized access to this state chances are this shared state will get corrupted. But you don't need to hit the method at the same nanosecond by 20 requests to corrupt your shared state. 2 suffice largely if you don't synchronize it.

So static methods by themselves are not evil (well actually they are as they are not unit test friendly but that's another topic), it's the way they are implemented that matters in a multithreaded environment. So you should make them thread safe.

---

UPDATE:

Because in the comments section you mentioned LINQ-TO-SQL as long as all variables used in the static method are local, this method is thread-safe. For example:

```
public static SomeEntity GetEntity(int id)
{
    using (var db = new SomeDbContext())
    {
        return db.SomeEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The static class is used for a linq-to-sql query. Bad idea?

Comment: @frenchie, as long as this static class doesn't rely on static resources that are not thread-safe you should be fine.

Comment: @frenchie, I have updated my answer to provide an example of a thread-safe method that could be used with Linq-To-SQL.

Comment: Ok, cool, that's how my class is written. If I want to be super safe, should I take 10-15 minutes and convert to class instantiation?

Comment: @frenchie, yes, you should take 10-15 minutes to convert this to a non-static class that you would put in your DAL layer. But you should do this not because this implementation is not safe. You should do it in order to weaken the coupling between the calling code and the data access code.

Comment: I do understand the difference between static classes and instantiated objects. But how will the coupling be any different if the calling class will still be calling the same method on the DAL instantiated object? Can you explain this in 1-2 lines?

Comment: @frenchie, with non-static classes you would define an interface. This interface will serve as a contract and contain the data access methods. Then you will implement this interface. For example using LINQ-TO-SQL. Then all your consuming objects will work only with the data access interface. This way the consuming code doesn't even know about LINQ-TO-SQL. All it needs to know is that there is a contract. This will also make your classes weakly coupled, reusable and unit testable in isolation. If you use a static class it means that you are strongly tying the consumer to LINQ-TO-SQL.

Answer (score 6):

It entirely depends on what your "some work" means. If it doesn't involve any shared state, it's absolutely fine. If it requires access to shared state, you'll need work out how to handle that in a thread-safe way.

A general rule of thumb is that a class's public API should be thread-safe for static methods, but doesn't have to be thread-safe for instance methods - *typically* any one instance is only used within a single thread. Of course it depends on what your class is doing, and [what you mean by thread-safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).

Comment: I'm using the class for a linq-to-sql query; it that a bad idea? Should the class not be static and be instantiated for every use?

Comment: @frenchie: It's a fairly vague term - read the linked blog post. But in hand-wavy terms it means "bad things won't happen if multiple threads call the same code at the same time" within some particular context.

Comment: @frenchie: The Linq2SQL DataContext itself is not thread-safe. As long as each helper call initializes its own context, and you don't access any other statically shared resources, you should be fine

Comment: @frenchie: You should create a new LINQ to SQL DataContext *within the method*, not storing it in a static variable. Do you have any variables which are shared between multiple threads? (What static variables do you have?)

Comment: Yes, the class creates a new datacontext within. I decided to change the class from static to instantiating an object within the calling class. That was, there for sure won't be any ooooopsss mistakes later on.

Answer (score 2):

you must ensure your methods are thread safe, so don't use static attributes to store any kind of state. If you are declaring new objects inside the static method, there is no problem because each thread have its own object.

Comment: if two or more threads execute a method at the same time, you need to ensure the access to shared resources are controlled, otherwise you obtain unexpected behavior. This is a sort resume of thread-safe term

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the static class has any state or not (i.e. static variables shared across all calls).  If it does not, then it's fine.  If it does, it's not good.  Examples:

```
// Fine
static class Whatever
{
    public string DoSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}

// Death from above
static class WhateverUnsafe
{
    static int count = 0;
    public int Count() {
        return ++count;
    }
}
```

You can make the second work fine using locks, but then you introduce deadlocks and concurrency issues.

I have built massive web applications with static classes but they never have any shared state.

Comment: Ok; I'm using the static class for a linq-to-sql query. Am I screwed if I do this? I was thinking that but keep the class static, I save the cost of instantiating the object.

Comment: I doubt you'd have to worry about object instantiation cost.  It's not expensive, plus I'm not sure if Linq2Sql is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes out in a nasty way (if you are doing this to share state), avoid doing this in a webapp... Or alternativly protect the reads/writes with a lock:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

But honestly you really should avoid using statics, unless you REALLY have to, and if you really have to you have to be very careful with your locking strategy and test it to destruction to make sure have managed to isolated reads and writes from each other

Comment: Who said anything about reads and writes? There's no evidence that this is using *any* shared state.

Comment: @Jon : Assumption is a dangerous thing ;p  I had assumed OP was doing this to share state between threads.  I updated my post to reflect this just as you posted your comment.